# Extraer los users y tags de éste sitio

Tags: python, python-requests

Tengo este código, pero necesito que me muestre solo los users y los tags de los usuarios de ésta
página, solo que cuando lo imprimo como se muestra ahí me muestra información que no necesito, traté
con la etiqueta de los usuarios pero no tienen un atributo ya que solo tiene un href

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://es.stackoverflow.com/users'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

tags = soup.find_all('div', class_='user-details')

names = list()

for i in tags:
        names.append(i.text)

print(names)
```

Comment: ¿por qué no usas la API del sitio en lugar de scraparlo?

Comment: Disculpa, me podrías dar una idea de cómo hacer eso?

Comment: https://api.stackexchange.com en https://api.stackexchange.com/docs hay buena documentación de todos los endpoints y cómo usarlos

Answer (score 1):

De esta forma puedes extraer los users.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url = 'https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=newusers'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for users in soup.find_all('div', class_='user-details'): #Especifica Etiqueta y clase
    print(users.getText().split("\n")[1]) #extraemos el texto y elegimos solo los users
```

Con el `split()` puedes separar el texto dependiente de lo que especifiques, En este caso el texto extraído mostraba un salto de linea después del nickname del usuario y luego seguia la reputacion y otras cosas, Aprovechamos ese salto de linea para separar el nickname de lo demas y elegimos la posicion nro 1, ya que antes del nickname tambien hay un salto de linea, Entonces[0] - primer salto de linea, [1] - nickname del user, [2] siguiente salto de linea.

en el caso de los tags, Al momento de raspar todo el html de la pagina no muestra los tags. solo muestra la etiquetas que seria `<div class="user-tags"></div>` por eso mismo no veo la forma de extraer eso.

puedes verlo tu mismo con esto.

```
for tags in soup.find_all('div', class_="user-tags"):
    print(tags)
```